# Zoom to a plot with GeoPandas based on data from CSV and shapefile

Tags: python, geopandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import descartes
import geopandas as gpd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame as gdf
%matplotlib inline

street_map = gpd.read_file('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\raccoon_island\\raccoon_island.shp')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 15)) 
street_map.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv('F:\\Anaconda\\docs\\OneDrive_1_9-29-2020\\11.csv')
df = df[['longitude_start','latitude_start']]
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
df.head()
```

[image]

```
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip( df["longitude_start"], df["latitude_start"])]
geometry[:3]

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs = crs, geometry = geometry)
geo_df.head()
```

[image]

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 15))
street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color='grey')
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, color='red', markersize=20, marker = '+', label= 'pos')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})
```

[image]

I have tried the following but it only seems to make the outer box change size. I would like to zoom in on the result instead.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (30, 30))
street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color='grey')
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, color='red', markersize=20, marker = '+', label= 'pos')
ax.set_ylim(auto=True)
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})

ax.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax), ylim=(ymin, ymax))

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = gdf.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are setting limits at three different places. Just pick one.

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (30, 30))
street_map.plot(ax = ax, alpha = 0.4, color='grey')
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, color='red', markersize=20, marker = '+', label= 'pos')
plt.legend(prop={'size': 15})

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = gdf.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
africa = world[world.continent == 'Africa']
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))

ax = africa.plot()
cities.plot(ax=ax, color='r')

minx, miny, maxx, maxy = africa.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx, maxx)
ax.set_ylim(miny, maxy)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you that solved my issue

Comment: How can I zoom the map just to the country South Africa (bottom one), there is no `country` attribute only a `continent` one? Would `minx` and `miny` be latitude and longitude?